# linux alternatives command database (find a name)

Tags: linux, symlink, system-administration

I'm using a system that has various java versions installed and uses the "alternatives" command to switch between them. I know that I can change the Java version using this command:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Where '**java**' is the name for that list of alternatives. I'm interested in finding the list of names for all alternatives currently installed. For example, I know that 'alternatives' also manages a link to the jdk directory, but I can't figure out the name to give to --config so that I can choose an alternative.

How do I get a list of names of alternatives on a linux system?

Comment: `-l` or `--list` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope. That's not even an option in the alternatives command.

Comment: I mean something like [`update-java-alternatives --list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html)

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. update-java-alternatives isn't a command on my system. I may be missing your point, but what you show doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that:

"Metadata about the alternatives system can be found in the administrative directory, which defaults to `/var/lib/alternatives`."

I found that information at this URL:
http://www.quora.com/Alternatives-Linux-command/How-does-the-alternatives-system-work

Each file in that directory represents a '**name**' for an alternative. It turns out that alternatives can manage more than just the link to a single binary. It can manage related paths too!